# Is there a designation for this not-quite-exponential time?

Tags: terminology, landau-notation

I've been working and experimenting with an algorithm that *may* take time $O^*(2^\sqrt{n})$.  Here $O^*(f(n))$ simply neglects all polynomial terms.  I've seen [a comment on Scott Aaronson's blog](http://www.scottaaronson.com/blog/?p=394#comment-13888) that mentions graph isomorphism algorithms run in this time, too.  Actually, $O(2^\sqrt{n})$.  Is there a designation for this time?

I thought perhaps quasi-exponential may describe it, but I'm wondering if there is already a name/designation for it.

Comment: It's subexponential (and superpolynomial, if it's also in $\Omega$ of something similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two useful classes are sub-exponential, $c^{n^\epsilon}$ for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$, and quasi-polynomial, $c^{\log^k n}$ for $k > 1$. (In both cases, $c > 1$.)

The terms themselves sometimes have different meanings. For example, in some contexts "sub-exponential" means $2^{(1-\epsilon)n}$ for some $\epsilon > 0$, and in others it means $2^{o(n)}$.

Since the term "sub-exponential" is loaded, it is better to mention what you mean by it whenever you use it.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, being sub-exponential requires the time to be valid for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$.  So it seems that this wouldn't qualify for sub-exponential, correct?

Comment: @MattGroff, Subexponential is an overloaded term; see the first line of the [second definition on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-exponential_time),"Some authors define sub-exponential time as running times in $2^{o(n)}$".

Comment: The three definitions in common use for subexponential are $c^{n^\epsilon}$, $2^{(1-\epsilon)n}$, and the one Luke quoted (e.g. is $2^{n/\log n}$ sub-exponential?). When in doubt, mention both the term and the meaning you give to it.