# Give one example where it takes Non- deterministically exponential time to solve the problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, np

I am a starter in complexity theory though I have fair knowledge in Turing machine. I know what it means to be non-deterministically polynomial time solvable but I am trying to understand where the time goes beyond polynomial time even using non-deterministic concept. Is it possible or we can do everything in polynomial time using non-deterministic concept though in reality it can not be implemented. Therefore, I am looking for an example where we can't do it in polynomial time rather it takes exponential time even after using non-deterministic concept. Please explain clearly why it takes exponential time(non-deterministically).

Comment: Maybe you should have done more reading? Looking at the [complexity zoo](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~greg/zoology/diagram.xml), you see quickly that there are *many* classes "above" NP, and many of those are proper supersets. There are also meta results that state that there are arbitrarily hard problems; any introduction to complexity introduces one of these (or should).

Comment: "Please explain clearly why it takes exponential time" -- (interesting) lower bounds are hard to come by. Which means that the proofs are often tough, and even so they are frequently not very insightful. If we *knew* what makes problems hard, we'd probably be closer to solving the P?=NP question.

Comment: Note also that "takes at most polynomial time" and "takes at least exponential time" are not antonyms. [There's stuff in between](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21397/is-there-a-designation-for-this-not-quite-exponential-time). Some NP-hard problems even have [sub-exponential algorithms](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/9813/98) (depending on the definition of "sub-exponential")!

Comment: *non-deterministically* exponential time? Ok, computing `1 + 1` will *non-deterministically* be affected by cosmic rays, alpha particles and quantum fluctuations in the transistors which will, during some execution, by chance take exponential time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are problems that cannot be solved in polynomial time on a nondeterministic machine. Indeed, there are problems that cannot be solved on *any* Turing machine, such as the halting problem.

We know from the nondeterministic version of the [time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) that there are things that can be done in exponential time on a nondeterministic TM that cannot be done in polynomial time.  That is, $\mathrm{NP}\subsetneq\mathrm{NEXP}$.

Wikipedia gives several examples of [$\mathrm{NEXP}$-complete problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NEXPTIME#NEXPTIME-complete): these are examples of problems that are provably not in $\mathrm{NP}$.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the winning strategy between two people is NEXP?  I understand for every single choice of the first person we need to see all moves by the second person. I am getting confused that how it leads to exponential time?

Comment: @ViX28, if number of possible configurations is hyperexponential of the size of the field, it may take non-deterministically at least exponential time to solve it. Not for all problems, of course (unless $\mathsf{EXP = NEXP}$).

Comment: @ViX28 Different games have different complexities, depending on the rules of the game. For example, games that involve placing pieces on a board but never moving or removing them (e.g., tic-tac-toe and connect 4) can typically be solved in $\mathrm{PSPACE}$ but games where pieces can move around can potentially have very long plays. For example, in chess the fact that I probably have about 30 moves available, to each of which you have about 30 replies, to each of which I have about 30 replies and so on naturally leads to exponential complexity.

Comment: Actually, Wikipedia's list of [complexities of well-known games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity#Complexities_of_some_well-known_games) doesn't include anything that's $\mathrm{NEXP}$-complete, so I've removed that claim from my answer. One could certainly invent $\mathrm{NEXP}$-complete games but that would be a pretty weak point.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Nondeterministic time hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem#Non-deterministic_time_hierarchy_theorem), $\mathsf{NEXP\neq NP}$, which means there are languages decidable in nondeterministic exponential time, but not with nondeterministic polynomial time. A simple consequence is that no $\mathsf{NEXP}$ complete problem can lie inside $\mathsf{NP}$, which means that the following language requires exponential nondeterministic time to solve:

$L=\left\{\left(n,\langle M\rangle,x\right) \big|\hspace{1mm} \exists w\in\{0,1\}^{\le n} : M(x,w)\right\}$

Note that if in the above you replace the binary representation of $n$ with its unary representation $1^n$ then the problem becomes $\mathsf{NP}$ complete rather then $\mathsf{EXP}$-complete. This is an example of a more general phenomena, where many $\mathsf{NP}$ complete problems can be turned into $\mathsf{EXP}$-complete problems by giving a succinct description of the inputs. More details about this and some examples of more natural $\mathsf{EXP}$-complete problems can be found in this [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/nexp-complete-problems) from cstheory.